# turtlebot teleop and follower apps do not work

Tags: turtlebot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I just received my Turtlebot 2/Kubiki base. It comes with Groovy pre-installed in the ASUS Laptop.
I wanted to start the two demo applications

So, I did

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

and
roslaunch turtlebot_follower follower.launch
As in Tutorial, I opened an ssh from my PC and run the launch files.

For "`roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch`" I get the following error:

```
IOError: Errno 13 Permission denied: '/home/turtlebot/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
[turtlebot_teleop_keyboard-1] process has died [pid 22131, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_teleop/scripts/turtlebot_teleop_key turtlebot_teleop_keyboard/cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop __name:=turtlebot_teleop_keyboard __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f6daa71c-7692-11e2-8049-446d57c5292a/turtlebot_teleop_keyboard-1.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f6daa71c-7692-11e2-8049-446d57c5292a/turtlebot_teleop_keyboard-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done


and for "roslaunch turtlebot_follower follower.launch" I get the following error:

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan_loader (nodelet/nodelet)
    follower (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_camera_loader (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/depth/
    points (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    follower_velocity_smoother (nodelet/nodelet)


core service [/rosout] found
process[follower_velocity_smoother-1]: started with pid [19259]
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [19304]
process[camera/openni_camera_loader-3]: started with pid [19327]
process[camera/depth/rectify_depth-4]: started with pid [19385]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 55, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 107, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 501, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 419, in load_cached_sources_list
    with open(cache_index, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/turtlebot/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
[rospack] Error: could not call python function 'rosdep2.rospack.init_rospack_interface'
[librospack]: error while executing command
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  rospack could not find the nodelet package containing nodelet::Nodelet
process[camera/depth/points-5]: started with pid [19464]
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 19304, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f6daa71c-7692-11e2-8049-446d57c5292a/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f6daa71c-7692-11e2-8049-446d57c5292a/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log
respawning...
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2] restarting process
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [19486]
process[camera/depthimage_to_laserscan_loader-6]: started with pid [19596]
process[camera/follower-7]: started with pid [19762]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 55, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 107, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 501, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 419, in load_cached_sources_list
    with open(cache_index, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/turtlebot/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
[rospack] Error: could not call python function 'rosdep2.rospack.init_rospack_interface'
[librospack]: error while executing command
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  rospack could not find the nodelet package containing nodelet::Nodelet
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 19486, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f6daa71c-7692-11e2-8049-446d57c5292a/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f6daa71c-7692-11e2-8049-446d57c5292a/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log
respawning...
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2] restarting process
```

Any help?

Thanks
**Anis**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55183/turtlebot-teleop-and-follower-apps-do-not-work/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-14**:
What user do you use for ssh?

**Comment by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on 2013-02-14**:
I used "ssh turtlebot@IP_ADDRESS_TURTLEBOT" I also executed the demo from turtlebot itsefl and the same problem occurs

**Comment by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on 2013-02-14**:
I used "ssh turtlebot@IP_ADDRESS_TURTLEBOT"

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-14**:
That should be correct. I don't know how their default image is set up. A fix might be to re-run `sudo rosdep init`, `rosdep update`, but maybe it's supposed to work differently, so I don't give any guarantees that this doesn't interfere somewhere else.

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-05**:
Can you teleop from the Turtlebot Laptop? If yes, then it is connection problem. If not, then it is ROS problem.

**Comment by [lawr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4807/lawr/) on 2013-05-02**:
exactly the same problem happened to me, could you give me a hint about what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there was a bug in the tutorial. delete the .ros directory manually and rerun the rosdep commands above should fix this.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saravanabalagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/38730/saravanabalagi/) on 2018-11-27**:
2018 and it works